# Bit strings with at most two consecutive identical digits

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to develop a recurrence relation for $T(n)$, the number of bit strings of length $n$ with a maximum of two consecutive $0$s or $1$s

I find the recurrence relation
$$T(n) = 2T(n-1) + T(n-2)$$
Is this right?

Comment: Do you mean $2T(n-1)-T(n-2)$? We have $T(1)=2,T(2)=4,T(3)=6\ne2\cdot4+2$. With that change it looks correct. Proof is fairly obvious, you can add either 0 or 1 at the end of any of the $T(n-1)$ solutions, but then you must remove those which end in 00 or 11 and there are $T(n-2)$ of those.

Comment: $T(1)=2,T(2)=4, T(3)=8-2=6$ but $6\neq 2\times 4 +2$.  Indeed, $2\times 4+2=10$ is greater than the total number of strings of length $2$.

Comment: (typo:  meant "strings of length $3$" at the end of my prior comment.)

Comment: or it must be T(n) = T(n-1) + T (n-2)

Comment: You should explain the reasoning that led to your formula.  It is much easier to check logic than to solve the problem independently

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following graph:

[image]

For each binary string we start from the blue state (empty string) and move along the graph according to the next character (I didn't mark them to the arrows but it should be obvious which is which, anyway it doesn't matter for the calculation).

Consider  the walks of length $n$ along the graph (or in another words binary strings of length $n$). For each state $X$ we want to count the number of these that start from the blue state and end up in $X$. By symmetry, this number is same for states $0$ and $1$, denote this by $a_n$. Similarly for the states $00$ and $11$, denote this by $b_n$. For the blue state, this number is $1$ for $n=0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now we can see from the graph that

- $a_n = a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$ and $a_0=0, \space a_1=1$
- $b_n = a_{n-1}$ and $b_0=0, \space b_1=0, b_2=1$

From these we get $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ which is the familiar [Fibonacci numbers](http://oeis.org/A000045). So $a_n=f_n$.

We want to count the strings that aren't rejected: $T_n = 2(a_n+b_n) = 2(f_n+f_{n-1})=2f_{n+1}$, (and the blue state), so we have

$$T_n = 2f_{n+1}, \space n>0, \text{ and } T_0=1$$